# Dir() function understanding

Tags: vba, excel, directory

```
' Display the names in C:\ that represent directories.
MyPath = "c:\"   ' Set the path.
MyName = Dir(MyPath, vbDirectory)   ' Retrieve the first entry.
Do While MyName <> ""   ' Start the loop.
      ' Use bitwise comparison to make sure MyName is a directory. 
      If (GetAttr(MyPath & MyName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then 
         ' Display entry only if it's a directory.
         MsgBox(MyName)
      End If   
   MyName = Dir()   ' Get next entry.
Loop
```

I am looking at the above code. I specifically don't understand what the "MyName = Dir()" does. It is commented it gets the next entry, but I don't understand how it gets the next entry - specifically what is Dir() doing?

Comment: I recommend you use FileSystemObject or FileDialog rather than Dir().

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers why?

Comment: `FileSystemObject` is *much* easier to use for tasks like this.  The code above can basically be boiled down into this: `For Each foo In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("C:\").SubFolders: MsgBox (foo.Path): Next`

Comment: @Comintern Could you explain the "Scripting.FileSystemObject" part? Why do you need the scripting aspect

Comment: That's just the library that the object is from - it's part of the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".  You could also early bind it by adding the reference. [There are examples in Documentation.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function)

> Dir returns the first file name that matches pathname. To get any additional file names that match pathname, call Dir again with no arguments. When no more file names match, Dir returns a zero-length string (""). After a zero-length string is returned, you must specify pathname in subsequent calls, or an error occurs.

So `Dir` is a function which has an edge effect.

the first call to `Dir`: `MyName = Dir(MyPath, vbDirectory)` initializes the `Dir` internals and returns the first directory entry.

Subsequent calls to `Dir` use the same context, yielding `MyPath` directory contents one by one.

It's not reentrant (which is also why you can't nest/recurse multiple loops using Dir), not very elegant, but that's how it works.

Comment: Which is also why you can't nest multiple loops using Dir

Comment: @TimWilliams right, not reentrant! if you want to do this, you have to store the full list of files, and perform the recursive call afterwards.

Comment: I admit to not being clear on "reentrant" (until I just looked it up)...

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre , Please could you provide any documentation for your answer , or you found out it by practice ?

Comment: it's all in the documentation, linked in my answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`Dir()` MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx), it

> Returns a string representing the name of a file, directory, or folder that matches a specified pattern or file attribute, or the volume label of a drive.

Comment: following your link I just stumbled upon the sample code that the OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

See in python Dir() function return a list of all packages/modules that are present inside a module . Like this!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wTtZ.png)

Comment: The question is about VBA scripting, not python